# Wrong output in Visual Studio Code while running C

Tags: c

I was learning on how to make a 2D array and print it but there is a problem with the output

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5][5], b, c, d;

    for ( b = 1; b < 6; b++)
    {
        for ( c = 1; c < 6; c++)
        {
            a[b][c] = b * c;
            printf("%d ", a[b][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

this here is the code

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10        
3 6 9 12 15       
4 8 12 16 4199157 
5 10 15 20 25
```

and this here is the output.

as you can see on row 4 of the output there should be a 20 instead of 4199157,

I compiled the same code in GDB c compiler online and the error was fixed

so is it a visual studio bug or is it something else?

Comment: What book, website or course are you learning C from?  Pretty much the first thing any respectable learning resource will teach you about arrays in C is that they are indexed _from zero, not one_.  PS: to answer your question, _no_ it's not a bug in the compiler -- it's a bug in your code that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: "*same code in GDB c compiler online and the error was fixed*" Except it was not. You must have missed that [`Segmentation fault`](https://onlinegdb.com/SksaBjwZd) line at the end.

Comment: Also visual-studio and vs code have nothing to do with this, even if it were a bug in the compiler it woudn't be the fault of the editor.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely zero need to use an array for this program.  Unless you plan to do something else with these values later.

Comment: The fact that you've got two different results with two different compilers indicates you that you're facing a [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can't expect a reliable behavior in that case.

Comment: in most of cases it's bug in your code. don't blame 3rd party software, you won't learn much with this attitude

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int a[5][5], b, c, d;

for ( b = 1; b < 6; b++)
{
    for ( c = 1; c < 6; c++)
    {
        a[b-1][c-1] = b * c;
        printf("%d ", a[b-1][c-1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

if you don't want to change the size just see where i have out (-) minus sign do that and it should work
or just change value of array to a[6][6]

Comment: this will do four unnecessary arithmetic operations.

Comment: Can you explain why my code didn't work, your answer is correct but I would like to know what I did wrong so that I don't make that mistake again

Comment: its because array start at 0 not at 1 and the size that you declared was a[5][5] that's 0-4 and you used size less then 6 that mean for loop will run till 5 but the size is just 0-4

Comment: @dreamcrash It was my first attempt to help , was not organised properly i edited it later

Answer (score 2):

The start index for arrays is 0 and not 1 so just change your code to:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5][5], b, c, d;

    for ( b = 0; b < 5; b++)
    {
        for ( c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            a[b][c] = b * c;
            printf("%d ", a[b][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```